# How to save checkbox value with shared preferences?

Tags: android, android-fragments, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I don't know why my code not save `checkbox` checked value; if I check `checkbox` and after I click on another tab and comeback to previous tab, `checkbox` is not selected...I hope that you find the error in my code!

IDE says to me: `FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException at line ".onCreateView(holder.chkBox.setChecked(true);"`

Why?

ADAPTER CLASS:

```
public abstract class PlanetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Planet> implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

    private List<Planet> planetList;
    private Context context;
    ArrayList<Birra> objects;

    public PlanetAdapter(List<Planet> planetList, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item, planetList);
        this.planetList = planetList;
        this.context = context;
    }    

    public class PlanetHolder {
        public TextView planetName;
        public TextView distView;
        public TextView valuta;
        public CheckBox chkBox;
        public EditText edit;
        public String quantità;        
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        PlanetHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_listview_item, parent, false);
            holder = new PlanetHolder();
            holder.planetName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.distView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dist);
            holder.valuta = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.valuta);
            holder.chkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);
            holder.edit = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            holder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.edit.setEnabled(false);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (PlanetHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        final Planet p = planetList.get(position);        
        final PlanetHolder finalHolder = holder;

        holder.chkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()) {
                    finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(true);
                    SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("MaterialTabs", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = preferences.edit();
                    mEditor.putBoolean("CheckBox_Value", finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked());

                    mEditor.commit();

                    finalHolder.edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            p.setQuantità(finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());
                            SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                            editor.putString("KEY", finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());

                            editor.commit();

                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(false);
                    finalHolder.edit.setText(null);

                }

            }
        });
        holder.planetName.setText(p.getName());
        holder.distView.setText("" + p.getDistance());
        holder.valuta.setText("" + p.getValuta());
        holder.chkBox.setChecked(p.isSelected());
        holder.chkBox.setTag(p);
        holder.edit.setEnabled(false);

        return row;
    }

    ArrayList<Planet> getBox() {
        ArrayList<Planet> box = new ArrayList<Planet>();
        for (Planet p : planetList) {
            if (p.selected)
                box.add(p);
        }
        return box;
    }
}
```

FRAGMENT:

```
ListView lv;
ArrayList<Planet> planetList;
PlanetAdapter plAdapter;
BirraAdapter biAdapter;
PlanetAdapter.PlanetHolder holder;

 public class MyListFragment extends Fragment implements
        android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Planet> planetList;
    PlanetAdapter plAdapter;
    BirraAdapter biAdapter;
    PlanetAdapter.PlanetHolder holder;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment    
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);

        Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            showResult(v);


            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        lv = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);
        displayPlanetList();
    }


    private void displayPlanetList() {

        planetList = new ArrayList<Planet>();
        planetList.add(new Planet("Margherita", 6, "€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Diavola", 7,"€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Bufalina", 5,"€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Marinara", 5,"€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Viennese", 4, "€"));

        plAdapter = new PlanetAdapter(planetList, getContext()) {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
                if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    Planet p = planetList.get(pos);
                    p.setSelected(isChecked);      
                }        
            }
        };
        lv.setAdapter(plAdapter);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        //get the instance variables
        SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("MaterialTabs", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean mCheckBoxValue = preferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", false);

        if (mCheckBoxValue) {
            holder.chkBox.setChecked(true);        
        } else {
            holder.chkBox.setChecked(false);            
        }
        super.onPause();   
    }

    public void showResult(View v) {
        String  result2 = "Selected Product are :";
        int totalAmount2=0;

        String a="";
        for (Birra b : biAdapter.getBox()){

            if (b.selected){

                result2 += "\n" + b.name+" "+b.distance+"€"+"q.tà :"+b.getQuantità();
                int quantitaInt= Integer.parseInt(b.getQuantità());
                totalAmount2+=b.distance * quantitaInt;
            }
        }

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result2 + "\n" + "Total Amount:=" + totalAmount2 + "€", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                        
    }                
}
```

Comment: What is `holder` in your fragment?

Comment: object of class "PlanetHolder"

Comment: You should not have a reference to a view holder outside of your adapter

Comment: so how i must modify my code ? :)

Comment: check boxes are in Adapter (custom) views of ArrayAdapter Right?

Comment: This code is kind of messy. As it stands there is too much junk included. You should reduce it to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If the code was cleaner I would put a bounty on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can store boolean values on shared preferences. Here's an example.

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor myPrefsPrefsEditor;
static final String MY_SHARED_PREF = "name_of_your_shared_pref";
```

Initialize your shared preferences

```
myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences(MY_SHARED_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Store your values using the following.

```
myPrefsPrefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
myPrefsPrefsEditor.putBoolean(key, value);
myPrefsPrefsEditor.commit();
```

key = use to find the value from shared pref

value = the value you want to store

This is how your read your values

```
myPrefs.getBoolean(key, defaultValue);
```

key = the key of the value you want to get

defaultValue = the default value when there's no value for the given key.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but i must also create a XML with checkbox checked?

Comment: It depends on the needs of your app. If you have the checbox on your xml. You need to get these values by looking at your parent layout's child views. Or you can hook an event that triggers the checked action and store its value.

Comment: with tinyDB is more simple?

Comment: Again, it depends on your app.

Comment: It's in my answer above.

Comment: but for tinyDB i must import a library?

Comment: You asked how to use shared preferences. You should create a new question regarding tinyDB.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        p.setQuantità(finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());
                        SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("KEY", finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());
                        editor.putBoolean("CheckBox_Value", finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked());
                        editor.commit();

}
```

and then retrieve it using getBoolean as you have already done

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);



        checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);                          
        SavedPreferences();

    }


    private void savePreferences(boolean value) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager

                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putBoolean(value);

        editor.commit();

    }





public class activity2 extends fragment{

       public onCreateView extends Fragment {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager

                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        boolean checkBoxValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", false);    

        if (checkBoxValue) {

            checkBox.setChecked(true);

        } else {

            checkBox.setChecked(false);

        }


    }



    }
```

Comment: i must write  private void savePreferences(boolean value) in adapter?

Comment: i call that savePreferences in onCreate is not have to do with adapter its save your chackBox

Comment: sorry, but i am not understanding

Comment: ok, now if i click on another tab with list view with checkbox, program not crash but when i came on previous tab with list view with checkbox, checkbox previous checked now is not checked....while if i click on tab without list view and comeback to previous tab, checkbox previous checked is checked...