# shared preferences and onPause doesn't work

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-studio, checkbox

if i check a checkbox and go on tab without list view with checkbox and came to previous tab, i see checkbox checked previously...but if i click on another tab with list view with checkbox, my program crash...why?
now i post my code...
I hope that you can help me!

Thanks in advance!

ADAPTER CLASS:

```
public abstract class PlanetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Planet> implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

    private List<Planet> planetList;
    private Context context;
    ArrayList<Birra> objects;


    public PlanetAdapter(List<Planet> planetList, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item, planetList);
        this.planetList = planetList;
        this.context = context;
    }


    public class PlanetHolder {
        public TextView planetName;
        public TextView distView;
        public TextView valuta;
        public CheckBox chkBox;
        public EditText edit;
        public String quantità;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        PlanetHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_listview_item, parent, false);
            holder = new PlanetHolder();
            holder.planetName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.distView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dist);
            holder.valuta = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.valuta);
            holder.chkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);
            holder.edit = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            holder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.edit.setEnabled(false);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (PlanetHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        final Planet p = planetList.get(position);


        final PlanetHolder finalHolder = holder;




    /*  SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("MaterialTabs", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

      boolean mCheckBoxValue = preferences .getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", false);
      if (mCheckBoxValue) {
          holder.chkBox.setChecked(true);
      } else {
          holder.chkBox.setChecked(false);
      }*/

        holder.chkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()) {
                    finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(true);
                    SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("MaterialTabs", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                 /* SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                  editor.putBoolean("showActivity", finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked());
                  editor.commit();*/
                    // boolean value= true;
                    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = preferences.edit();
                    mEditor.putBoolean("CheckBox_Value", finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked());

                    mEditor.commit();

                    finalHolder.edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            p.setQuantità(finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());
                         /* SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                          editor.putString("KEY", finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());

                          editor.commit();*/

                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(false);
                    finalHolder.edit.setText(null);

                }

            }
        });
        holder.planetName.setText(p.getName());
        holder.distView.setText("" + p.getDistance());
        holder.valuta.setText("" + p.getValuta());
        holder.chkBox.setChecked(p.isSelected());
        holder.chkBox.setTag(p);
        holder.edit.setEnabled(false);

        return row;
    }


    ArrayList<Planet> getBox() {
        ArrayList<Planet> box = new ArrayList<Planet>();
        for (Planet p : planetList) {
            if (p.selected)
                box.add(p);
        }
        return box;
    }
}
```

FIRST FRAGMENT CLASS WITH LISTVIEW WITH CHECKBOX:

```
public class MyListFragment extends Fragment implements android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Planet> planetList;
    PlanetAdapter plAdapter;
    BirraAdapter biAdapter;
    PlanetAdapter.PlanetHolder holder;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);


        Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showResult(v);


            }
        });
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);
        displayPlanetList();
    }


    private void displayPlanetList() {

        planetList = new ArrayList<Planet>();
        planetList.add(new Planet("Margherita", 6, "€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Diavola", 7, "€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Bufalina", 5, "€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Marinara", 5, "€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Viennese", 4, "€"));

        plAdapter = new PlanetAdapter(planetList, getContext()) {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
                if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    Planet p = planetList.get(pos);
                    p.setSelected(isChecked);


            /*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Pizza: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                }


            }
        };
        lv.setAdapter(plAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        //get the instance variables
        SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("MaterialTabs", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean mCheckBoxValue = preferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", false);

        if (mCheckBoxValue) {
            holder.chkBox.setChecked(true);


        } else {
            holder.chkBox.setChecked(false);


        }
        super.onPause();
    }


    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        /*int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
        if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            Planet p = planetList.get(pos);
            p.setSelected(isChecked);


            *//*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Planet: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*//*
        }*/

    }


    public void showResult(View v) {
        String result2 = "Selected Product are :";
        int totalAmount2 = 0;

        String a = "";
        for (Birra b : biAdapter.getBox()) {

            if (b.selected) {

                result2 += "\n" + b.name + " " + b.distance + "€" + "q.tà :" + b.getQuantità();
                int quantitaInt = Integer.parseInt(b.getQuantità());
                totalAmount2 += b.distance * quantitaInt;
                //a=String.valueOf(totalAmount);


            }
        }
    /*  for (Planet p : plAdapter.getBox()) {
            if (p.selected){

                result += "\n" + p.name+" "+p.distance+"€"+"q.tà :"+p.getQuantità();
                int quantitaInt= Integer.parseInt(p.getQuantità() );
                totalAmount+=p.distance * quantitaInt;
                //a=String.valueOf(totalAmount);


            }
        }*/
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result + "\n" + "Total Amount:=" + totalAmount + "€", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result2 + "\n" + "Total Amount:=" + totalAmount2 + "€", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        /*Bundle bun2 = new Bundle();
        bun2.putString("scelta", result);
        TwoFragment fgsearch2 = new TwoFragment();
        fgsearch2.setArguments(bun2);
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction2.replace(R.id.content_main, fgsearch2);
        transaction2.commit();


        Bundle bun = new Bundle();
        bun.putString("totale", a);
        TwoFragment fgsearch = new TwoFragment();
        fgsearch.setArguments(bun);
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_main2, fgsearch);
        transaction.commit();*/
    }
}
```

SECOND FRAGMENT WITHOUT LISTVIEW:

```
public class TwoFragment extends Fragment {

    private View v;
    Intent chooser = null;


    public TwoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
        Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newbutton);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                sendemail();


            }
        });
        TextView titolo3 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.result2);
        TextView titolo2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.quantità2);
        //TextView titolo = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.quantità3);

        Bundle bundle2 = getArguments();
        if (bundle2 != null) {
            String string = bundle2.getString("scelta2", null);
            titolo3.setText(string);
        }
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            String myInt = bundle.getString("totale2", null);
            titolo2.setText(myInt);

        }
       /*  Bundle bundle3=getArguments();
        if(bundle3 != null){
             String valuta=bundle3.getString("valuta", null);
             titolo.setText(valuta);

        }*/
        return rootView;
    }

    public void sendemail() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        String[] to = {"marco_marcoletto@hotmail.it"};
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "ciao");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "zao");
        intent.setType("message/rfc822");
        chooser = intent.createChooser(intent, "manda email");
        startActivity(chooser);
    }
}
```

THIRD FRAGMENT WITH LISTVIEW WITH CHECKBOX:

```
public class ThreeFragment extends Fragment implements android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    ListView lv2;
    ArrayList<Birra> birraList;
    BirraAdapter biAdapter;
    BirraAdapter.BirraHolder birraHolder;
    BirraAdapter.BirraHolder holderr;


    public ThreeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);

        Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showResult(v);


            }
        });
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        lv2 = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview2);
        displayBirraList();
    }


    private void displayBirraList() {

        birraList = new ArrayList<Birra>();
        birraList.add(new Birra("Paulaner", 6, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Forst", 7, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Peroni", 5, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Corona", 5, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Nastro Azzurro", 4, "€"));
        biAdapter = new BirraAdapter(birraList, getContext()) {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int pos = lv2.getPositionForView(buttonView);
                if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    Birra b = birraList.get(pos);
                    b.setSelected(isChecked);


            /*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Pizza: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                }


            }
        };
        lv2.setAdapter(biAdapter);
    }

   /* @Override
    public void onPause() {

        //get the instance variables
        SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("MaterialTabs", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean mCheckBoxValuee = preferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Valuee", false);

        if (mCheckBoxValuee) {
            holderr.chkBox_birra.setChecked(true);


        } else {
            holderr.chkBox_birra.setChecked(false);



        }
        super.onPause();
    }

*/

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


        /*int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
        if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            Planet p = planetList.get(pos);
            p.setSelected(isChecked);


            *//**//**//**//*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Planet: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*//**//**//**//*
        }
*/
    }


    public void showResult(View v) {
        String result = "Selected Product are :";
        int totalAmount = 0;
        String c = "";

        for (Birra b : biAdapter.getBox()) {
            if (b.selected) {

                result += "\n" + b.name + " " + b.distance + "€" + "q.tà :" + b.getQuantità();
                int quantitaInt = Integer.parseInt(b.getQuantità());
                totalAmount += b.distance * quantitaInt;
                c = String.valueOf(totalAmount);


            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result + "\n" + "Total Amount:=" + totalAmount + "€", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       /* Bundle bun2 = new Bundle();
        bun2.putString("scelta2", result);
        TwoFragment fgsearch2 = new TwoFragment();
        fgsearch2.setArguments(bun2);
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction2.replace(R.id.content_main, fgsearch2);
        transaction2.commit();


        Bundle bun = new Bundle();
        bun.putString("totale2", c);
        TwoFragment fgsearch = new TwoFragment();
        fgsearch.setArguments(bun);
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_main2, fgsearch);
        transaction.commit();*/
    }
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
05-10 12:34:17.975 20371-20371/info.androidhive.materialtabs E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at info.androidhive.materialtabs.activity.MyListFragment.onPause(MyListFragment.java:103)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performPause(Fragment.java:2139)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1117)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.detachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1408)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:727)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:254)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please attach the exception stack trace.

Comment: ok, i just posted logcat

Comment: declare your checkbox in FirstFragment. I think you have not declared it

Comment: if i write "holder." IDE suggest me "chkBox"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save checkbox value with shared preferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132658/how-to-save-checkbox-value-with-shared-preferences)

Answer (score 0):

Your holder in method onPause(MyListFragment) was not instantiated. So when it came to the line

```
holder.chkBox.setChecked(true);
```

That exception would come out

Comment: so i must instantiated holder.chkBox.setChecked(false) in method onPause?

Comment: You dont have to do that in method onPause. But you must instantiate holder before that line

Comment: how i instantion holder?

Answer (score 0):

**java.lang.NullPointerException** means you are trying to use a component that is not initialized.

here, your motive is setChecked/unChecked of checkbox into `PlanetAdapter` from `onPause()` callback. You can do in this way:

1. Create an Interface that will communicate between fragment to your adapter.
2. In your `onPause` callback send command to your adapter for check/uncheck of your checkbox list.

Example:
Suppose your interface is like it:

```
public interface AdapterCallback {
    void onCheckboxCallback(boolean isChecked);
}
```

In your Adapter implements `AdapterCallback` Interface. Then you will get `onCheckboxCallback()` method.

```
@Override
    public void onCheckboxCallback(boolean isChecked) {
//      Do your checkbox check/uncheck here
    }
```

In this method you can checked/unchecked based on your isChecked value.

Now, in your Fragment/Activity that populating PlanetAdapter, just call this method

```
if (mCheckBoxValue) {
            plAdapter.onCheckboxCallback(true);


        } else {
            plAdapter.onCheckboxCallback(false);
```