# Checkbox not saving when reopening

Tags: java, android, android-studio, checkbox

I have 3 classes relating to my checkbox section of my app in Android studio, atm the check box loads, but when selecting and deselecting the value doesn't save when I go bak into it from the main menu. any help would great!!!
public class WatchList extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    ArrayList dataModels;
    ListView listView;
    private WatchListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("watchlist", "created watchlist activity");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_watch_list);


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview2);

        dataModels = new ArrayList();

        dataModels.add(new WatchListClass(R.drawable.kookaburra,"Kookaburra","Albury", false));
        dataModels.add(new WatchListClass(R.drawable.cockatoo, "Cockatoo" , "Bathurst", true));
        dataModels.add(new WatchListClass(R.drawable.emu,"Emu", "Echuca", true));
        dataModels.add(new WatchListClass(R.drawable.magpie, "Magpie", "Sydney", true));

        adapter = new WatchListAdapter(dataModels, getApplicationContext());

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                WatchListClass dataModel= (WatchListClass) dataModels.get(position);
                dataModel.checked = !dataModel.checked;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
public class WatchListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private ArrayList dataSet;
    Context mContext;


    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView birdWatchName, birdWatchLocation;
        ImageView birdWatchImage;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }

    public WatchListAdapter(ArrayList data, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.watch_list, data);
        this.dataSet = data;
        this.mContext = context;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }

    @Override
    public WatchListClass getItem(int position) {
        return (WatchListClass) dataSet.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.watch_list, parent, false);
            viewHolder.birdWatchImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.birdWatchImage);
            viewHolder.birdWatchName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.birdWatchName);
            viewHolder.birdWatchLocation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.birdWatchLocation);
            viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

            result=convertView;
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result=convertView;
        }

        WatchListClass item = getItem(position);

        viewHolder.birdWatchImage.setImageResource(item.birdWatchImage);
        viewHolder.birdWatchName.setText(item.birdWatchName);
        viewHolder.birdWatchLocation.setText(item.birdWatchLocation);
        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(item.checked);


        return result;
    }
}
```

```
public class WatchListClass {

    public String birdWatchName, birdWatchLocation;
    int birdWatchImage;
    boolean checked;

    WatchListClass(int birdWatchImage, String birdWatchName,String birdWatchLocation, boolean checked) {
        this.birdWatchName = birdWatchName;
        this.birdWatchLocation = birdWatchLocation;
        this.birdWatchImage = birdWatchImage;
        this.checked = checked;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can user shared preferences for check Box

try this one

[How to save checkbox value with shared preferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132658/how-to-save-checkbox-value-with-shared-preferences)

you can use local database in app to store check box values and retrieve it back.